# Sequelize - How can I return JSON objects of the database results only?

Tags: javascript, json, sequelize.js

So I'm wanting to have the database results returned and nothing else. At the moment I'm getting returned a large chunk of JSON data (Like below):

But I'm only needing the [dataValues] attribute. I don't want to have to use the this bit of `JSON` to retrieve it: `tagData[0].dataValues.tagId`.

I just noticed: When it finds and **DOESN'T CREATE**, it will return the `JSON` for the database results, but when it **DOESN'T FIND** and creates, it returns the un-needed JSON blob (Like below) Is there a way around this?

```
[ { dataValues:
     { tagId: 1,
       tagName: '#hash',
       updatedAt: Fri Dec 25 2015 17:07:13 GMT+1100 (AEDT),
       createdAt: Fri Dec 25 2015 17:07:13 GMT+1100 (AEDT) },
    _previousDataValues:
     { tagId: 1,
       tagName: '#hash',
       createdAt: Fri Dec 25 2015 17:07:13 GMT+1100 (AEDT),
       updatedAt: Fri Dec 25 2015 17:07:13 GMT+1100 (AEDT) },
    _changed:
     { tagId: false,
       tagName: false,
       createdAt: false,
       updatedAt: false },
    '$modelOptions':
     { timestamps: true,
       instanceMethods: {},
       classMethods: {},
       validate: {},
       freezeTableName: true,
       underscored: false,
       underscoredAll: false,
       paranoid: false,
       whereCollection: [Object],
       schema: null,
       schemaDelimiter: '',
       defaultScope: null,
       scopes: [],
       hooks: {},
       indexes: [],
       name: [Object],
       omitNull: false,
       sequelize: [Object],
       uniqueKeys: [Object],
       hasPrimaryKeys: true },
    '$options':
     { isNewRecord: true,
       '$schema': null,
       '$schemaDelimiter': '',
       attributes: undefined,
       include: undefined,
       raw: true,
       silent: undefined },
    hasPrimaryKeys: true,
    __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
    isNewRecord: false },
  true ]
```

Instead of getting the big blob like the above I only need the `RAW` json results (Like below):

```
{ tagId: 1,
       tagName: '#hash',
       updatedAt: Fri Dec 25 2015 17:07:13 GMT+1100 (AEDT),
       createdAt: Fri Dec 25 2015 17:07:13 GMT+1100 (AEDT) },
```

I've used the following javascript. I did try add `raw: true`, but it didn't work?

```
    // Find or create new tag (hashtag), then insert it into DB with photoId relation
module.exports = function(tag, photoId) {
    tags.findOrCreate( { 
        where: { tagName: tag },
        raw: true
    })
    .then(function(tagData){
        // console.log("----------------> ", tagData[0].dataValues.tagId);
        console.log(tagData);
        tagsRelation.create({ tagId: tagData[0].dataValues.tagId, photoId: photoId })
        .then(function(hashtag){
            // console.log("\nHashtag has been inserted into DB: ", hashtag);
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log("\nError inserting tags and relation: ", err);
        });
    }).catch(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

}
```

#### Edit:

So I've investigated a bit and it seems that the big `JSON` blob is only returned when `Sequelize` is creating and not finding.

Is there a way around this or not?

#### Edit 2:

Okay so I've found a workaround, which could be turned into a re-usable function. But if there's something built into `Sequelize`, I'd prefer to use that.

```
var tagId = "";

// Extract tagId from json blob
if(tagData[0].hasOwnProperty('dataValues')){
    console.log("1");
    tagId = tagData[0].dataValues.tagId;
} else {
    console.log("2");
    console.log(tagData);
    tagId = tagData[0].tagId;
}

console.log(tagId);
tagsRelation.create({ tagId: tagId, photoId: photoId })
```

#### Edit 3:

So, I don't think there is an "Official" sequelize way of achieving this so I simply wrote a custom module which returns the `JSON` data that's needed. This module can be customised and extended to suit various situations! If anyone has any suggestions to how the module can be improved feel free to comment :)

In this module we're returning a Javascript Object. If you want to turn it into `JSON` just stringify it using `JSON.stringify(data)`.

```
// Pass in your sequelize JSON object
module.exports = function(json){ 
    var returnedJson = []; // This will be the object we return
    json = JSON.parse(json);


    // Extract the JSON we need 
    if(json[0].hasOwnProperty('dataValues')){
        console.log("HI: " + json[0].dataValues);
        returnedJson = json[0].dataValues; // This must be an INSERT...so dig deeper into the JSON object
    } else {
        console.log(json[0]);
        returnedJson = json[0]; // This is a find...so the JSON exists here
    }

    return returnedJson; // Finally return the json object so it can be used
}
```

#### Edit 4:

So there is an official sequelize method. Refer to the accepted answer below.

Comment: There is an "Official" Sequelize way to do this, please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Though poorly documented, this does exist in Sequelize.

Couple Ways:

**1.**  For any response **object** that resulted from a query, you can extract only the data you want by appending `.get({plain:true})` the the response like so:

```
Item.findOrCreate({...})
      .spread(function(item, created) {
        console.log(item.get({
          plain: true
        })) // logs only the item data, if it was found or created
```

Also make sure you are using the `spread` callback function for your type of dynamic query promise. And note that you have access to a boolean response, `created`, which signifies whether or not a create query was executed.

**2.** Sequelize provides the `raw` option. Simply add the option `{raw:true}` and you will receive only the raw results. This will work on an array of results, the first method should not, as `get` will not be a function of an array.

Comment: Nice one. Sorry for accepting it so late, I saw it briefly then forgot it had an answer.

Comment: I posted an update with `async/await` syntax, feel free to integrate it to your answer

Answer (score 12):

If you want to work only with the [values of an instance](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/#values-of-an-instance) try to call `get({plain: true})` or `toJSON()`

```
tags.findOrCreate( { 
    where: { tagName: tag }
})
.then(function(tagData){
     console.log(tagData.toJSON());
})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I get `[TypeError: undefined is not a function]`. I guess I'm just going to have to write my own function to extract the plain `JSON`

Comment: @James111, oh sorry, try to use without `raw: true` parameter in query

Comment: Be sure not to ask `toJSON()` in a list, like I just did. Not the case for the question, just for someone searching.

Comment: This can be used with the results of .findOne() or a single object of a findAll(). On an array, .toJSON() function will throw un-defined

Answer (score 5):

Updated:

Use `data.dataValues`

```
db.Message.create({
    userID: req.user.user_id,
    conversationID: conversationID,
    content: req.body.content,
    seen: false
  })
  .then(data => {
    res.json({'status': 'success', 'data': data.dataValues})
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    res.json({'status': 'error'})
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

**Now easier to read with `async/await` syntax**

```js
module.exports = async function(tagName) {
  const [tag, created] = await Tag.findOrCreate({
    where: {tagName},
    defaults: {tagName}
  });
  return tag.get({plain:true});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sequelize-values` is an npm-module which helps you do this. It has methods which easily prints the values on both single item and list of results (array)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-values

Answer (score -2):

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await Model.findAll({}))));
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.